# How do I create child windows with Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am using Python 3.3 and tkinter to make a GUI interface for a pedestrian fleeing simulation.

I've written two simulation programs, and they worked well. However,I got stuck when trying to call them from my main application. I want the simulation window to appear in a separate window (create a child window of the main window).

```
#flee_GUI.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tkinter

class MenuBar(tkinter.Menu):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Menu.__init__(self,parent)
        ###File###
        fileMenu = tkinter.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File",underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label='Open',underline=1)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)
        ###Run###
        runMenu=tkinter.Menu(self,tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label='Run',underline=1,menu=runMenu)
        runMenu.add_command(label='Open Bounary Model',underline=1,command=runModel1)


class Frame(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent

def runModel1():
    from drawcanvas_Alpha_7_0_open_border import cell
    I=cell(None)

class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        runModel1()

        menubar=MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=App(None)
    app.mainloop()

#drawcanvas_Alpha_7_0_open_border.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

#Run this by python3.x.
#If you are using Python2.x,be aware of the difference such as print,Tkinter and tkinter,etc.

#from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import random

#class cell(Frame):
class cell(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):

        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.channel_length=40#aisle length (1 unit for 10 pixel)
        self.channel_width=40#aisle width
        self.origin_x=0
        self.origin_y=0
        self.pixel_unit=10
        self.speed=100
        self.alltime=0
        self.PN=100#Number of pedestrian
        self.Pu=0.1
        self.Pd=0.9#probability of going down if the right side were occupied
        self.window_width=self.origin_x+self.channel_length*self.pixel_unit
       self.window_height=self.origin_y+self.channel_width*self.pixel_unit+2*self.pixel_unit
        self.canvas=tkinter.Canvas(
    self.parent,width=self.window_width,height=self.window_height,bg='lightblue')

        self.Ped_x=[]
        self.Ped_y=[]
        self.block_flag=[]
        self.block_occupy=[]
        self.draw_canvas()
        self.draw_grid()
        self.draw_architecture()
        self.draw_pedestrian_init()
        self.draw_pedestrian()


    def draw_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.pack()
    def destroy_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.destroy()
    def destroy_architecture(self):
        pass
    def draw_grid(self):
        for i in range(2,self.channel_width+1):
            self.draw_line(0,i,self.channel_length,i)
        for i in range(1,self.channel_length):
            self.draw_line(i,0,i,self.channel_width+1)



    def draw_line(self,x0,y0,x1,y1,linedash=1):
        self.canvas.create_line(
        self.origin_x+x0*self.pixel_unit,
        self.origin_y+y0*self.pixel_unit,
        self.origin_x+x1*self.pixel_unit,
        self.origin_y+y1*self.pixel_unit,dash=linedash)

    def draw(self,x0,y0,x1,y1,color='black'):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(
        self.origin_x+x0*self.pixel_unit,
        self.origin_y+y0*self.pixel_unit,
        self.origin_x+x1*self.pixel_unit,
        self.origin_y+y1*self.pixel_unit,
        fill=color)
        for i in range(y0,y1):
            for j in range(x0,x1):
                self.block_occupy[i][j]=1
                #print(j,i)
    def draw_architecture(self):

        for i in range(0,(self.channel_width+1)+1):
            self.block_occupy.append([])
            for j in range(0,self.channel_length):
                self.block_occupy[i].append(0)
        self.draw(0,0,self.channel_length,1)
         self.draw(0,self.channel_width+1,self.channel_length,self.channel_width+2)

        self.draw(30,1,31,int(self.channel_width/2-1),'red')
        #self.draw(30,int(self.channel_width/2+1),31,self.channel_width+1,'red')

    def draw_pedestrian_init(self):
        Ped_count=0
        while Ped_count<self.PN:
            self.Ped_x.append(
            int(random.randrange(
        self.origin_x,self.origin_x+30*self.pixel_unit)/self.pixel_unit)*self.pixel_unit)

            self.Ped_y.append(
            int(random.randrange(
            self.origin_y+self.pixel_unit,self.origin_y+(self.channel_width+1)*self.pixel_unit)/self.pixel_unit)*self.pixel_unit)
            tmp_x=int((self.Ped_x[Ped_count]-self.origin_x)/self.pixel_unit)
            tmp_y=int((self.Ped_y[Ped_count]-self.origin_y)/self.pixel_unit)
            if self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]==1:
                self.Ped_x.pop()
                self.Ped_y.pop()
            else:
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]=1
                Ped_count=Ped_count+1


        self.block_flag=[self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.Ped_x[i],self.Ped_y[i],
        self.Ped_x[i]+self.pixel_unit,self.Ped_y[i]+self.pixel_unit,fill='green') for i in range(0,self.PN)]
    def draw_pedestrian(self):
        for i in range(0,self.PN):
            self.canvas.delete(self.block_flag[i])

        #print(self.block_occupy)
        #count_f=self.PN
        for i in range(0,self.PN):
            if self.Ped_x[i]>self.origin_x+(self.channel_length-1)*self.pixel_unit-1:
                #self.Ped_x[i]=self.Ped_x[i]-self.channel_length*self.pixel_unit
                dummy_x=int((self.Ped_x[i]-self.origin_x)/self.pixel_unit)
                dummy_y=int((self.Ped_y[i]-self.origin_y)/self.pixel_unit)
                self.block_occupy[dummy_y][dummy_x]=0
                #count_f=self.PN-1
                self.Ped_x[i]=-1
                self.Ped_y[i]=-1
        temp_block_flag1=[]
        temp_block_flag2=[]
        for i in range(0,self.PN):
            if self.Ped_x[i]!=-1:
                temp_block_flag1.append(self.block_flag[i])
            else:
                temp_block_flag2.append(self.block_flag[i])
        self.block_flag=temp_block_flag1
        for i in range(0,len(temp_block_flag2)):
            self.canvas.delete(temp_block_flag2[i])


        self.Ped_x=[self.Ped_x[i] for i in range(0,self.PN) if self.Ped_x[i]!=-1]
        self.Ped_y=[self.Ped_y[i] for i in range(0,self.PN) if self.Ped_y[i]!=-1]
        self.PN=len(self.Ped_x)

        for i in range(0,self.PN):
            print(self.PN,i,len(self.Ped_x))
            tmp_x=int((self.Ped_x[i]-self.origin_x)/self.pixel_unit)
            tmp_y=int((self.Ped_y[i]-self.origin_y)/self.pixel_unit)

            if self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x+1]==0:
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]=0
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x+1]=1
                self.Ped_x[i]=self.Ped_x[i]+self.pixel_unit


            elif (self.block_occupy[tmp_y+1][tmp_x]==0 
            and self.block_occupy[tmp_y-1][tmp_x]==0):#The right side is occupied,while the up and down side is free
                if random.uniform(0,1)<self.Pd:#go down
                    self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]=0
                    self.block_occupy[tmp_y+1][tmp_x]=1
                    self.Ped_y[i]=self.Ped_y[i]+self.pixel_unit
                else:#go up
                    self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]=0
                    self.block_occupy[tmp_y-1][tmp_x]=1
                    self.Ped_y[i]=self.Ped_y[i]-self.pixel_unit

            elif (self.block_occupy[tmp_y+1][tmp_x]==1 #the up side is occupied,while the down side is free
            and self.block_occupy[tmp_y-1][tmp_x]==0):
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]=0
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y-1][tmp_x]=1
                self.Ped_y[i]=self.Ped_y[i]-self.pixel_unit
            elif (self.block_occupy[tmp_y+1][tmp_x]==0 #the up side is free,while the down side is occupied 
            and self.block_occupy[tmp_y-1][tmp_x]==1):
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y][tmp_x]=0
                self.block_occupy[tmp_y+1][tmp_x]=1
                self.Ped_y[i]=self.Ped_y[i]+self.pixel_unit

        #print(self.block_occupy)

        self.block_flag=[self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.Ped_x[i],self.Ped_y[i],
        self.Ped_x[i]+self.pixel_unit,self.Ped_y[i]+self.pixel_unit,fill='green') for i in   range(0,self.PN)]

        self.alltime+=1
        self.after(self.speed,self.draw_pedestrian)
        if self.PN==0:
            print("Fleeing complete!,total time:",self.alltime)

            self.destroy_canvas()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Io=cell(None)
    Io.mainloop()
```

How can I launch a child window from my main application with tkinter?

Comment: The example code should be replaced with a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's fairly lengthy, and mostly unrelated to the specific issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You create child windows by creating instances of `Toplevel`. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm for more information.

Here's an example that lets you create new windows by clicking on a button:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you also plz tell whether we can show or hide this window? meaning is there an alternative to pack and pack_forget for it?

Comment: Oh thanks, I have found out the answer for my question from your other post so I decided why not add it to the answer of yours to make it easier for other people who have this problem to get the full basic understanding.

Comment: Oh, now I have ran into an error with these functions, -:

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"

Comment: Can you plz help