# Browsing not shown for Python GUI Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have done a simple tkinter GUI, i wanted a browse button but it doesn't seem to appear

```
#!/usr/bin/env python      
import Tkinter as tk       

class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
        self.grid()                       
        self.quit_program()

    def quit_program(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
          command=self.quit)            
        self.quitButton.grid()

    def browse_file(self):
        self.browseButton = tk.Button(self, text='Browse',
          command=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Open file to encrypt'))
        self.browseButton.grid()

app = Application()                       
app.master.title('Sample application')    
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need to pack the button with frame container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python      
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)   
        self.grid()                       
        self.quit_program()
        self.browse_file()
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('musicfiles', '.mp3'),('vediofiles', '.mp4')]

        options['parent'] = self
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'

    def quit_program(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',
          command=self.quit)            
        self.quitButton.grid()

    def browse_file(self):
        self.browseButton = tk.Button(self, text='Browse',command=self.askopenfile)
        self.browseButton.grid()
    def askopenfile(self):
        return tkFileDialog.askopenfile(**self.file_opt )

app = Application()                       
app.master.title('Sample application')    
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: nataraj Сундар if i want to filter out the file dir to only mp3 or mp4,how do i do that?

Comment: @user3817491 http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog please check this there is file options change file options to mp4 and mp3

Comment: nataraj Сундар     def askopenfile(self):
        return tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    # define options for opening or saving a file
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.mp3'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.mp3')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.txt'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'

Comment: nataraj Сундар  def askopenfile(self):
        return tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    # define options for opening or saving a file
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.mp3'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.mp3')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.mp3'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'

Comment: nataraj Сундар i got the codes working together with the addition of mp4. How do i go to a new page along with the file?

Comment: nataraj Сундар i can't post another question for 90 minutes. Do you have any ways so that i can chat with you because i really need help?

Comment: @user3817491 please go throught the http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog you will find solution

Comment: nataraj Сундар okay i am sorry. I hope you will be patient with me. For now,i just need to bring it to a new page of the GUI

Comment: @user3817491 its ok . have look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306631/how-tocreate-children-windows-using-python-tkinter here

Comment: nataraj Сундар i checked it already but how do i get it to be the same size? not a pop out dialog

Answer (score 0):

Three mistakes in your code

1. What is `tkFileDialog`? Have you imported it? Import it by adding `import tkFileDialog` at the top of your file
2. What is `root`? Change `root` to `self`.
3. The `command` argument in the `tk.Button` is not meant to be used the way you have. You should not call the method in the command argument. You should specify a method to be called when the button is clicked. In your example, you are telling tkinter, to call the value returned by `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` instead of calling `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename`. So replace it with another method or use a lambda.
   `command=lambda : tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Open file to encrypt')`