# Tkinter I want to delete a frame and replace it with another

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently started learning python and even more recently the Tkinter module. For practice I decided to create a window environment that works a bit like mySQL workbench. Everything was fine until I found out that submitting a second query doesn't actually remove the previous one.
My code for the button callback is as follows:

```
def queryBtnCallBack():
    global query
    global queryEntry
    global resList
    global resFrame
    j=1
    #Delete frame before showing next data
    for widget in resFrame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    #For this one I also tried
    #if resFrame != None:
    #   resFrame.destroy()

    cursor = db.cursor()

    resFrame = Tkinter.Frame()
    #Check if user has given a correct input
    try:
        query = queryEntry.get()
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    #Let user know if something is wrong
    except:
        errorQLabel = Tkinter.Label(resFrame, text='Error. Please make sure your query is correct', bg='#99b3e6')
        errorQLabel.grid(row=j+1, column=2)
        resFrame.configure(background='#99b3e6')
        resFrame.pack()
        return 

    for i in data:
        resList.append(i)

    #Query Results window part
    for i in range(len(resList)):
        j += 1
        resultLabel = Tkinter.Label(resFrame, text=resList[i], bg='#99b3e6')
        resultLabel.grid(row=j, column=2)

    resFrame.configure(background='#99b3e6')
    #Pack the results frame
    resFrame.pack()
```

The way I'm doing it now, it deletes the frame, but then puts the next one underneath the now-deleted one.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: may be you should inherit concepts of child and parent windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306631/how-tocreate-children-windows-using-python-tkinter

Comment: +1 for updating the existing widget(s) with the new text, but to delete the frame, delete resFrame.  This will delete all of the widgets within the frame so it is not necessary to delete wininfo_children results.  So start with resFrame=None at the top of the program (not the function), so you have an object to test on the first pass and it should work fine.

Comment: The comment in the code says you tried `resframe.destroy()`. What happened? That looks like the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to make this more complex than it needs to be. I'd suggest just keeping one big label and reconfiguring it with new text to show the new data, maybe with newlines inserted into the data to keep the sections separate. To get rid of the previous query from the entry widget, just do `queryEntry.delete('0', 'end')`.