# Pygubu Load new Window from UI File

Tags: python, tkinter, pygubu

I have been looking through *Pygubu examples* trying to best understand how to achieve my goal with no success.

I am VERY new to python, have only just started with it a few days ago. I have a number of functions that work well and accept a range of variables to do tasks but now I want to try and create a GUI to handle the inputs before firing up the functions etc.

Because I am new to it, I thought I would try Pygubu, especially since I am using a *windows machine*. I had a look at their examples and found out how to load the `MainWindow` which I have designed.

My main window is basically a menu system loaded from Panorama.ui, it has a few buttons which are designed to be pressed to open up other windows ("SphericalWindow", "Gigapixel_Window and "Settings").

I have played with the callback function, and that works fine in pulling up a `messagebox`, however where I get stuck is how to call one of the other windows to be opened.

I saw an example that talks about opening child windows at [How do I create child windows with Python tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306631/how-tocreate-children-windows-using-python-tkinter) but I am not really sure how that is translated to open a frame from within a UI file?

How would that example, where a top-level window is created e.g. below be converted so that `tk.Toplevel` is being built from a UI file?

```
t = tk.Toplevel(self)
```

Thanks for any help.

```
import sys
import os

try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))

import pygubu


class Myapp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()
        fpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Panorama.ui")
        builder.add_from_file(fpath)

        mainwindow = builder.get_object('MainWindow', master)

        builder.connect_callbacks(self)


    def on_Gigapixel_Click(self):
        #Callback to open window here.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Myapp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this thread is rather old, I'll still answer it as I stumbled upon it searching for a similar solution which I have figured out by now.

My Pygubu file looks as follows:
[image: I made up a minimal example of what I understood from your specifications.]

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # for python 3
    from tkinter import messagebox
except:
    import Tkinter as tk  # for python 2
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox

import threading
import pygubu

class Application:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        builder.add_from_file('Panorama.ui')

        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('MainWindow', master)

        builder.connect_callbacks(self)

    def openSphericalWindow(self):

        builder2 = pygubu.Builder()
        builder2.add_from_file('Panorama.ui')
        top2 = tk.Toplevel(self.mainwindow)
        frame2 = builder2.get_object('SphericalWindow', top2)
        builder2.connect_callbacks(self)


    def quit(self, event=None):
        self.mainwindow.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()

def startUI():

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(target=startUI)
    t.start()
```

This then opens a settings window with three buttons of which the SphericalWindow-Button opens a new window.

[image]

Hopefully this might help someone in the future!

Cheers,
Tim