# Python/Tkinter - How can I create infinite copies of a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a window that is constantly created making many copies of its-self.

I have tried making an infinite loop that calls the function every time but that doesn't work. I also tried making one within the function but it just recreates the window after I close the old one. Does this mean that the window can't be duplicated?

```
import tkinter 
import os


def win():
    A = True
    while A == True:
        window = tkinter.Tk()
        window.title('WHOOPS')
        window.geometry('100x100')
        window.configure(background= "green")
        lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text= 'whoops', bg= 'red')

        window.mainloop()


quit = False
while quit == False:
    win()
```

Can someone show me how to duplicate a window without hard-coding a whole new block, for example, a new function for each of win2() and win3()?

The user should be able to see a practically infinite stream of windows that can only be stopped by using the KeyboardInterrupt or by closing the shell/interpreter.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15306785/3368572

Comment: You also don't have to have `A = True` and then `While A == True:` you can just have `While True:`

Comment: You might run into some hardware limitations with this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create windows in a infinite loop you are never going to return control to the main_loop. You can follow one of the followings:

**#1** You can initialize an integer to 0 and after a specific count update root and then again continue creating windows and after a specific count update root again and it goes on ...

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def startInfiniteLoop():
    i = 0
    otherFrame = []
    while True:
        otherFrame.append(tk.Toplevel())
        i += 1
        if i%1000 == 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            root.update()

root = tk.Tk()
button_one = tk.Button(root, text="Infinite Window !", command=startInfiniteLoop)
button_one.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

**#2** You can write a function that creates a window and from inside of that function call itself after specific time again and again.

```
import tkinter as tk

def startInfiniteLoop():
    otherFrame = tk.Toplevel()
    root.after(1000, startInfiniteLoop)

root = tk.Tk()
button_one = tk.Button(root, text="Infinite Window !", command=startInfiniteLoop)
button_one.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will never see the new windows because your function never returns control to `mainloop`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for correcting me. I have updated my answer.