# How to avoid tkinter from popping up a window during import?

Tags: python, tkinter, import, popup

Is there a way to run `root = tk.Tk()` without popping out a window?

I am using Python3.8.3 with tkinter UI. I am trying to run a script (I will call it side script, apologies if there is a better term for that) from my main script. The idea is, user will click a button on main script window and side script window will appear. If I run the side script alone, it works fine. If I call side script from main script, then I get error because root is a local variable. I can solve this error by defining root as global variable in the side script. However when I do it, importing side results in an empty tkinter window.

If side script is:

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
else:
    pass
```

*Error: name 'root' is not defined, when called from main script*

If side script is:

```
root = tk.Tk()

def main():
    app = MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
else:
    pass
```

root is now a global variable, but then *blank tkinter window pops up* during importing of this line `root = tk.Tk()`

Can you recommend me a good way to overcome this?

Comment: `root.withdraw()` hides the window and to bring it back, u can use `root.iconify()`

Comment: Your statement about that first block is incorrect. If I create a simple script that imports that first block, it will not give the error you say it does.

Comment: It really depends on the design of main script, but you didn't post your main script.

Comment: I guess I should have posted a larger part of the code. I was afraid that the focus would shift. Lesson learned. Anyway, I learned how to hide a window and what would be good way to fix it. Thank you all for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to run root = tk.Tk() without popping out a window?

No, there is not. The design of your code is flawed. You should not be importing a script that has that line of code at the global level.

The simplest solution is to move that line of code inside the `if` statement, exactly like you did in the first block:

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you're getting some error some from other part of code complaining about the global variable `root`, the fault is in that code, not in the code you are importing. The correct solution would be to remove the dependency on a global variable. That, or declare `root` as global inside `main`.

Comment: My code design is definitely bad. I am only a beginner. I will remove dependency, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the window popping up, let the side script take *root* as a argument.

Side script:

```
def main(my_root):
    app = MainApp(my_root)
    my_root.mainloop()
```

Even better than this, put everything inside one class. This way, it's all ordered together and you don't have to import anything. Also, if you're opening a window that is a child of the main window, you can use Toplevel.
[How do I create child windows with Python tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306631/how-do-i-create-child-windows-with-python-tkinter)